# scrollbar-width: none; VS overflow-x: hidden

Tags: css, scrollbar

It seems that I can use both these to hide the horizontal scrollbar of an element:

```
overflow-x: hidden;

scrollbar-width: none;
```

Which one is the better solution for hiding the horizontal scrollbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`overflow-x: hidden` will clip any content inside a parent element (say the page) that has a width that overflows out of the parent and prevent the user from scrolling horizontally. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x)

`scrollbar-width: none` hides the scrollbar however the content will still be scroll able. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width)

So it depends upon what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

With 
   `scrollbar-width: none;`
the scrollbar is still present and you can still scroll if there is overflow, if you want to disable scrolling at all use 
    `overflow: hidden;`